# Change clover target output dir (maven plugin)

Tags: maven, clover

Is there an option to change the directory where the maven clover plugin generates the html reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `outputDirectory`? See [docs](http://docs.atlassian.com/maven-clover2-plugin/2.3.1/clover-mojo.html).